# Accessing appView from Cordova 5.0.0

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm having real trouble to access `appView` from the latest Cordova version for Android (5.0.0).

For example, say I want to add a Javascript interface to my app. Before this version, I used to write this line of code:

```
super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "jsInterface");
```

And then the `WebAppInterface`:

```
public class WebAppInterface { ... }
```

Now, it just does not work. Has Cordova changed something recently? I seriously have no idea of what to do.

In both cases (previous version and new one), my main activity has this structure:

```
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        ...
}
```

Comment: the super.init saved my life. My this.appview would always be null..... Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After days looking for a solution, I finally get the app to work.

Cordova has changed the way to access Android `webView`. Developers using Cordova 5.0.0 and newer versions need to add this line to their main activity:

```
WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
```

And then, just call wV as usual. For example, to add a Javascript Interface:

```
wV.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "jsInterface");
```

I hope this answer will help other people who are confused about this new update.

Comment: I'm in a simliar "get this to run after 5 days" mood :-( In my onCreate method the this.appview and super.appview are null. I use XWalk (Crosswalk) but think this is just a question of casting the webview correctly. Anyway with a null you don't go anywhere.... Was this an IONIC app by accident 'cause mine is. See repo here, would love to have a little more insight into your solution: https://github.com/bitflower/IonicXwalkShouldInterceptRequestTest

Comment: See my comment on the main question: The super.init() was missing in the IONIC starter app. I don't underdstand this as the app was successfully running without it before. Anyway. Your thread was the right pointer after 3 days....

Comment: The casting works for evaIuateJavascript, but I don't get the interface in the window object.
Must I do this in the MainActivity or can I do this in my plugin code (which would result more useful)?

Comment: I wasn't getting the methods on my `window.jsInterface` object until I updated the `-keepclassmembers` setting in my proguard-project.txt file.

Answer (score 5):

I was about to give up before i found your answer, which helped me on a related problem - thanks josemmo.

Maybe this will help others:
After updating to Cordova 5 / Android 4 i couldn't get the shouldOverrideUrlLoading-Method of my WebViewClient to be triggered, because setting the WebViewClient on a newly created WebView

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

in the onCreate Method did nothing.

So the solution was to not create a new WebView, but to use the casted appView AND engine like so:

```
SystemWebViewEngine systemWebViewEngine = (SystemWebViewEngine) appView.getEngine();
WebViewClient myWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient(systemWebViewEngine);

WebView webView = (WebView) systemWebViewEngine.getView();
webView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
```

The custom WebViewClient class then needs a constructor:

```
public class myWebViewClient extends SystemWebViewClient {

    public myWebViewClient(SystemWebViewEngine systemWebViewEngine) {
        super(systemWebViewEngine);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I kind of doubt that this is how it should be done, but at least its working.