# Can't get appView after Update to cordova 5.1 from 3.4

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I updated my app to cordova 5.1 recently and I am unable to make web request from JS.

The only problem during compiling was 
inside onCreate function of my class that extends CordovaActivity

I used to do this

```
super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false)
```

now it says cast it... I tried
`(WebView)super.appView` but app crashed as its illegal cast

I read [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992669/accessing-appview-from-cordova-5-0-0)
and tried to do the same
(WebView)super.appView.getEngine().getView()
but I am still not able to make a web request.... on iOS/Desktop chrome it works fine so nothing is wrong in JS code

Comment: did you find a resolution?

Comment: @ntaj I found out 2 things one is add whitelist plugin which I didn't so I could not make a web request.... second is (WebView)super.appView.getEngine().getView().getSettings() is the right solution

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the `WebView` from the Cordova engine.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
```