# addJavascriptInterface not working correctly in cordova 5.4

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

So in my java code I have something like this

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(taskLoader, "project_internal");
```

In my javascript, I use the java object(`taskLoader`) through `project_internal` variable like below

```
project_internal.openProfileAuth();
```

But when I run my android project, I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: project_internal is not defined,
>   source:file:///android_asset/project/auth/js/projectjavascript.js

Has anything changed in this Cordova version? This had worked before in Cordova older versions.

Comment: how did u define ur webview reference? for cordova5 u need do it linke below: WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView(); see the link below for more info : [WebView] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992669/accessing-appview-from-cordova-5-0-0

Comment: what is appView in your case? It is definitely not referred this way in my code.

Comment: addJavascriptInterface has never been supported by cordova (it worked, but you shouldn't use it), you have to use phonegap plugins for the java-javascript communication