# How to add JavaScript Interface in Cordova Version 6.1.1 for Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordovawebview

I want to use a Java Class from the Javascript Code in Android. I figured out that using CordovaWebView.addJavaScriptInterface() it was possible.

But I guess that this is not possible in Version 6.1.1.
How to do it.
Or If there any other method that you can suggest???
Thanks

Comment: Try using plugins instead of addJavaScriptInterface() as addJavaScriptInterface() approach has potential security threats. Check out this link for info on security threats - http://d3adend.org/blog/?p=431

Comment: Possible duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30109668/1956278